# Serializing data in JSON and storing and retrieving it from a postgresqlDB in Django?

Tags: django

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Question(models.Model):
    question_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.question_name


class PythonQuestion(models.Model):
    question_no = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    question_text = models.TextField()
    question_testcase = models.TextField()
    question_difflevel = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.question_name
```

This is my models.py. As of now, I'm using the django admin page for viewing the models and storing data.

In the field question_testcase, I plan to store JSON data. Which is the better way to go about it?

1. To take the data as input from a view(non-serialized) and then serialize the data using django serializers.
   OR
2. To take the data from the input, serialize it using javascript and then send it to Django to store it in the db?

Comment: We can't decide whether or not you'll need to use JavaScript for your frontend.

Comment: I won't if its not necessary. All I am asking is which one is a better way to go about it and why.

Answer (score 0):

Doing anything in the front end without checking on the server too is error prone.
So checking on the server as well is a must. And client side checking is a nice to have.

My approach would be to validate the field with a json-deserializer. If it works, the record can be saved. If not, the admin interface should show a meaningful error.